# How to fix WinSCP error 'System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing' on SFTP Port

Tags: sftp, biztalk, winscp, winscp-net, biztalk-2016

I'm getting the following error on our BizTalk 2016 instance with a SFTP receive port when it polls to connect to a SFTP site:

> The Messaging Engine failed to add a receive location "OURPORTNAME" with URL "sftp://oursourceserver:22/Live/Pickup/Exports/*.*" to the adapter "SFTP". Reason: "WinSCP.SessionLocalException: Error parsing session log file ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing.
>        at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e) at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent() at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read() at WinSCP.SessionLogReader.DoRead()

Looking at the WinSCP site, it looks like the version of WinSCP that is tied to this version of BizTalk can have this error.

The version of WinSCP that comes with BT2016 is:

File Version: 1.5.4.8265
Product Version: 5.13.1.0

**I tried copying into the BizTalk install folder a new version 5.13.6 (1.5.6.9061) of the WinSCP assembly and EXE** and used the following instructions to update the Biztalk 32 and 64bit configuration files (BTSNTSvc.exe.config) to redirect to this new version of WinSCP:

Microsoft BizTalk [SFTP Adapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/sftp-adapter)

(See 'Use a newer WinSCP version')

So in both 64bit and 32bit configs I have:

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.5.4.8265" newVersion="1.5.6.9061" />
```

Having edited that and restarted the host instances, I am getting this from the SFTP port in the event log:

> The Messaging Engine failed to add a receive location "OURPORTNAME"
>        with URL "sftp://oursourceserver:22/Live/Pickup/Exports/*.*" to the
>        adapter "SFTP". Reason: "WinSCP.SessionRemoteException:  Network
>        error: Software caused connection abort at WinSCP.SessionLogReader.Read(LogReadFlags flags)    at WinSCP.ElementLogReader.Read(LogReadFlags flags)    at

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that after the upgrade there were firewall/connectivity problems that prevented it working on our test environment.

Comment: Don't forget to use the green tick next to your answer to mark this answer that solved your question.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was fixed in WinSCP 5.13.2:
[Bug 1619 – Failure when .NET assembly starts reading an XML log file in a short moment when it's empty yet](https://winscp.net/tracker/1619)

---

*For the problem you have with the newer version of WinSCP, consider posting a new question and do not forget to include a session log file (`Session.SessionLogPath`).*

Comment: Yes. As you can see from my question I have upgraded it to a new version and I get the error described.

Comment: I see in your question that after you upgrade, you get a completely different and unrelated error, than your question title says.

Comment: I did that because that is the original error. After getting that error I took another step to change to a non-standard (as far as Biztalk 2016 is concerned) version of WinSCP. I was unsure if that was the right step to correct the error, as I got a further error by doing that. It might be that my attempt to fix it was wrong with respect to BT.